# If the pod scales, only the main container scales or both main container and sidecar container scales?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, sidecar

In Kubernetes, sidecar container will be single container instance for entire replicas of main application container or each sidecar container per each replica of main application ?? If the pod scales, only the main container scales or both main container and sidecar container scales

Comment: The smallest management unit in k8s is a pod. Therefore if we scale a pod, we scale all its containers.

Comment: @Turing85 your comment should be in answer field. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/):

> *Pods* are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.

Therefore, if we scale a pod, we scale all its containers.